# Как задать автоматическое изменение размеров виджетов из Qt

Tags: c++, qt, qtcreator

Нужно измененять размеры вложенных виджетов с изменением размеров окна. Не пойму как, или нужно программировать это самому? Подскажите пожалуйста.

Comment: Читайте про `QLayout` и наследников, Вам нужны именно они.

Comment: Спасибо, я искал правила компоновки в свойствах виджетов, а здесь подход несколько другой.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3492739/auto-expanding-layout-with-qt-designer

Answer (score 2):

Лучше использовать QLayout, но можно сделать велосипед. 
Например, определить минимальные параметры разрешения(1280 на 720 и т.д.) и при изменении размеров главного окна делать ресайз всех виджетов.

Comment: Да меня устраивает и штатный компоновщик Qt.

Answer (score 0):

Определить поведение стандартного компоновшика можно на стадии визуального проектирования виджета. В выпадающем меню есть пункт "Компоновка" с несколькими вариантами управления виджетами, а так же тулбар, на самом видном месте. Можно так же воспользоваться визуальными объектами Layout, для размещения своих виджетов. Определение же нестандартного поведения требует программирования производного класса от QLayout.[image: Компоновка виджетов - проще некуда.]